# Ad Serving Disabled Due To Address Pin Not Verified in Admob Console - No Option To verify Adress Pin in Admob Dashboard Console

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense, google-play-console

My Admob Account shows message like, "Ad Serving disabled due to address pin not verified". Also, There is no option to verify pin. I have received one address PIN. But, there is no option to verify.

Also, There is no option to contact any admob authority for help.

Whenever I try the following link, https://admob.google.com/home/request-consult/ for consultation it doesn't work. I'm frustrated with google admob service.

Also, I have tried posting question on google support forum. But, no one is replying back to provide solution.

Let me know if anyone can help.

Thanks.

[image]